# Is there a generate java bean in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

So, we constantly generate java beans and frequently need

```
1. an optional constructor
2. fields
3. getters
3. optional setters
```

is there a quick wizard for this?  I know about generate constructor and generate getters/setters but it feels like it should be about time for a one step process.

Comment: I'd like to know this too, and put a bounty on it

Comment: The best I can figure is to create a class with private variable declarations, go into netbeans (probably exists similar in eclipse), choose encapsulation option and use the popup to quickly build getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Lombok, so you don't have to write or generate the getters, setters or constructor.
[Lombok @Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html)

You can fine-tune what you want by using @Getter, @Setter and @RequiredArgsConstructor instead of @Data